# Unir dos coordenadas de una matriz usando distancia mínima con R

Tags: r, matrices

Estoy trabajando en un proceso de completación (no estoy seguro si es el término correcto) de una matriz basada en dos coordenadas de preferencia considerando la distancia mínima, me explico.

Tengo una matriz de nxm (filas y columnas), de valores NA y 1 ver figura 1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El objetivo es:

1. Encuentre los puntos extremos de los elementos contiguos que están unidos por una distancia igual a 1 (adyacente en la horizontal y vertical) o 1.4142 (adyacente en la diagonal). Las coordenadas extremas en el ejemplo están representadas por los rectángulos de la figura 1.
2. Después de ubicar las coordenadas extremas de los grupos que tengas las distancias indicadas en el punto uno, se requiere completar las coordenadas que permita unir los dos extremos "**de preferencia**" considerar la distancia mínima entre los dos puntos. (ver líneas en la figura 1)

Suponiendo que encuentro las coordenadas extremas (a y b, ver figura 2), estoy tratando de usar la ecuación vectorial de una línea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
completa <- function(a, b, k){
  x <- y <- NULL
  resta <- b - a
  u_ba <- resta / sqrt(sum(resta^2))
  for (i in seq(0, 1, k)) {
    posi <- a + i * u_ba
    x <- c(x, posi[1])
    y <- c(y, posi[2])
  }
  coordenadas  <- cbind(x, y)
  return(coordenadas)
}
```

La matriz de ejemplo está en:

```
data_mat <- read.csv ("https://www.dropbox.com/s/hz42scjuf9uib9y/data_test.csv?dl=1")
```

considerando como ejemplo las coordenadas a y b
a <- c (25, 6)
b <- c (20, 10)

Al utilizar la función con las coordenadas con k = 0.5 (el valor de k puede variar entre 0 y 1), se obtiene lo siguiente:

```
completa (a, b, 0.5)
# x y
# [1,] 25 6
# [2,] 25 6
# [3,] 24 7
```

pero el resultado esperado es:

```
# x y
# [1,] 25 6
# [2,] 24 7
# [3,] 23 8
# [4,] 22 9
# [5,] 21 10 # o 21 9,
# [6,] 20 10
```

Es evidente que existe más de una solución para la línea, por lo que comentar que se puede considerar de preferencia la distancia mínima.

Finalmente, luego de tener estas coordenadas, solo bastaría con asignarles un valor igual a uno. La idea principal es hacer que este proceso sea recursivo. Y que al final se pueden unir todas las coordenadas de la matriz.

Por favor, cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Se me escapa un poco la forma en que lo estás resolviendo. En sí, para calcular los puntos `y` por cada `x` y poder completar los puntos de la recta que unen `a` y  `b`, solo necesitamos averiguar la pendiente, que en este caso sería:

```
a <- c(25, 6) 
b <- c(20, 10)

# diff(y)/diff(x)
(a[1]-b[1]) / (a[2] - b[2])
-1.25
```

Con la pendiente, podemos ir generando valores para `x`, según la resolución `k` y obtendremos los puntos `y`. Como se trata de una cuadrícula, los valores de `y` deberían ser discretos, por lo que podríamos redondearlos:

```
completa <- function(a, b, k) {
  
  x <- y <- numeric(0)
  
  resta <- b - a
  pendiente <- resta[1]/resta[2]
  u_ba <- c(pendiente, 1)
  
  for (i in seq(0, resta[2], k)) {
    posi <- a + (i * u_ba)
    x <- round(c(x, posi[1]),0)
    y <- round(c(y, posi[2]),0)
  }
  cbind(x, y)
}
```

Como verá, el ciclo ha cambiado ya que se va haciendo de `x1` a `x2` y con la `pendiente` calculamos el valor de `y`, también agregamos un redondeo a cada eje.

Ejemplo, con `k = 0.8` llegamos a una solución bastante óptima:

```
a <- c(25, 6) 
b <- c(20, 10)

completa(a, b, .8)

      x  y
[1,] 25  6
[2,] 24  7
[3,] 23  8
[4,] 22  8
[5,] 21  9
[6,] 20 10
```

Comment: alguna sugerencia de como podría generalizar la ubicación de los elementos extremos del conjunto de grupos adyacentes? (rectángulo cuadrado en la figura 1). Graciaa por la respuesta si cumple con su objetivo.

Comment: Tal vez con algún algoritmo de clustering tipo knn, pueda ir iterando con distintos parámetros para ir agrupando los puntos, más allá del enunciado, no sé muy bien cual es el objetivo final.